# Download an image from image url

Tags: python, django

I have simple django project and I want to download image from website to my media. Url looks like this:
`https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ks-_Mh1QhMc/hqdefault.jpg`

How can i do this using python 3.x?

Comment: you mean like automatically every day/each time you call the function or just one time?

Comment: Just one time one image. But i have much images to download(I save image url in my database field)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use **urllib.request**

```
import urllib.request as req

    imgurl ="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ks-_Mh1QhMc/hqdefault.jpg"

    req.urlretrieve(imgurl, "image_name.jpg")
```

Comment: In this case i must write my relative image path to directory which i use for images?

Comment: yes, eg->  req.urlretrieve(imgurl, "relative_path/image_name.jpg")